# SOAPUI replaces address with localhost

Tags: soapui

When ever I try to load a new WSDL into a project (existing or new) the address is being replaced with localhost. For example I copy from the web browser
http://192.168.1.1:8080/webservices/service1?wsdl
then I get an error stating
http://localhost:8080/webservices/service1?wsdl error loading ... attempted to read from closed stream.

I have verified the proxy (we don't use them). However, I did have it turned on at on point to 'record' the call using JMeter. But jmeter is no longer running.
If I enter an address to an external webservice it will load fine.

Ideas / suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: the ipaddress on my system is not 192.168.1.1 (just used as place holder) Also tried other servers that are on the same network. In command window verified I can ping by server name, server full name, ipaddress. There are no web apps running on my system.

Comment: tivaranas, I believe that soapui does not update endpoint url automatically. never noticed it. So, you can open the wsdl in browser without any issue?